# Problem with javax inject : NullpointerException

Tags: java, spring, web-services, nullpointerexception, inject

I am writing a simple REST webservice which using javax inject. Problem is the get method from javax.inject.Provider return null. Is there anything i am missing ?

Relevant code is as per below :-

```
@Inject
    private Provider<CcrBO> ccrBOProvider;

CcrBO bo = ccrBOProvider.get();
```

CCRBo class is declared as :-

```
@Named("CcrBO")
@Scope("prototype")
public class CcrBO {
```

The problem is the "bo" returned is null.

Comment: You are injecting a `Provider` not a `CcrBO`. Without any producer, `ccrBOProvider` can only be `null`

Comment: your ccrBOProvider variable is the cause of nullpointer. can you show your Provider class please

Comment: The Provider is a javax.inject interface.

Comment: @Lorelorelore The Provider is an interface which can take any template. here i am passing CCRBo in place of Template. ccrBOProvider is not null but the variable "bo"  is null i.e. the get function of the interface returns null for me.

Comment: @Damith  Below is the dependency i used :  <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: @Inject is pretty old one. last release was on 2009. Its highly recommonded to move into spring Component & Autowired annotations. 
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-autowire